# Sorting the date in JSON object angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am making an angular application where I get the JSON object as the response. In the response array I have a date element as "lastUpdatedBy" I want to sort the data through angular sort (orderBy) so that i get the latest updated data in the bottom.

For the comparison I am also taking the sysdate from the server in the same JSON object as "sysDate".

please provide me with a solution. as i don't know how to give the expression in the orderBy filter.

Answer (score 1):

There's a decent example of using orderBy here:

[AngularJS orderBy documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

You should just be able to do something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:'lastUpdatedBy'">
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.lastUpdatedBy}}</td>
</tr>
```

Perhaps it'd help if you showed us what `orderBy` you have tried, which isn't working...?

**Update**

You can also use this `orderBy` if you wanted to sort your data in your AngularJS controller, using something like this:

```
$scope.sortedArray = $filter('orderBy')($scope.unsortedArray, 'lastUpdatedBy', true);
```

And then you'd be able to get the most-recently updated item using:

```
$scope.sortedArray[0]
```

Comment: actaully my problem is that : I have a JSON Object Array 

and I want that Element should get sorted on the basis of one element of each object in JSON array I want it that way

Comment: I didn't quite understand your English, but see if the update I've made to my answer (above) answers your question.